# Difference between VAR vs SVAR

Tags: time-series, vector-autoregression

I've problem with the difference between the VAR and the structural VAR. I've read books and articles but I don'get the difference between these two since we use lower triangular matrix when imposing restrictions in a svar(by referring to the theory) , and the choleski decoposition to orthogonalize the shocks and studying the impulse response functions, which is the same techniques with the standard VAR (without reffering to the theory) I mean that it uses the same techniques so it gets the same result since we always estimate the reduce VAR!Can anyone help me to get this please

Comment: Any answer please, I'm in hurry !

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think VAR and SVAR are two alternative representations of the same underlying process. So the process they describe is the same, but the two models offer two different angles of viewing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After studying the issue I found out, if I'm not wrong, that the cholesky decoomposition is the simplest way to make a structural analysis I mean that when we use cholesky decomposition we're  making structural var, the inconvenient of this decomposition is that it imposes to restrict the superior side of my structural matrix to be all zero so it imposes neglecting some contemporanous relations between variables. Any one who can confirm this ?

Comment: I think you could still rewrite the model to get contemporaneous relationships. Alternative representations are tricky business...

Comment: I was looking for the same. This might help you.
http://vps.fmvz.usp.br/CRAN/web/packages/vars/vignettes/vars.pdf